# RegEx, How to get all matches and group? Ruby 1.9.3p125

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.3

Let's say I have the following string:

```
google-com, Awesome-net(Ooops), facebook-com / rocket-yet
```

I want to extract all the words ending with `-com` but have them grouped.

For now, I have tried:

```
^\w+[-]com
```

That works fine but only catches the first match. How to get all the others? Maybe something using parentheses but I can't figure out how to..

Having all the matched strings into an `MatchData` object (Ruby) I can work it like an `Array`.

I'm using ruby 1.9.3p125

```
1.9.3p125 :124 > original
 => "google-com, Awesome-net(Ooops), facebook-com / rocket-yet" 
1.9.3p125 :125 > results = original.match(/(\w+-com)/)
 => #<MatchData "google-com" 1:"google-com">
```

Comment: Don't use `[-]`. A bare `-` will do fine instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `match` wasn't the right method to go.

Changed to `scan` with the regex suggested by Ben Roux and Epic_orange make it works.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the findall option and this will work:

`\w+-com`

I tested it in http://rubular.com/

Comment: What does it return? You have to have it return all the matched strings with a certain function call-you probably using the wrong call if its only returning the first one.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: found the issue, your regex has a caret at the start, symbolizing that only an instance of this at the very beginning of a string will match. Removing it should allow you to match all groups within the string:

```
(\w+[-]com)
```

Comment: `/g` is not a valid regex option in Ruby.

Comment: In Rubular your regex looks like it is running globally, are you sure you are not just having ruby grab the initial instance?

Comment: Weird but testing this on `IRB` it catches the same first match twice. Any tip?